# How change the menu item to a different color according to its section using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

At the moment,my navbar does the following using jquery on my WordPress site:
When I scroll at about 150 px,it gets fixed to the top

```
var num = 150; //number of pixels before modifying styles
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
           $('nav#site-navigation').addClass('fixed');            
       } else {
           $('nav#site-navigation').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Then as I scroll down to about, the about menu item get highlighted...then as I scroll down to products section,the products and services menu item gets highlighted,the about dehighlihts and so forth.

```
$("nav ul li a").addClass("marker");    
    var navLinks = $('nav ul li a'),
    navH = $('nav').height(),
    section = $('section'),
    documentEl = $(document);        
    documentEl.on('scroll', function() {            
      var currentScrollPos = documentEl.scrollTop();            
      section.each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        if (self.offset().top < (currentScrollPos + navH ) && (currentScrollPos + navH) < (self.offset().top + self.outerHeight())) {
            var targetClass = '.' +self.attr('class') + 'marker';
            navLinks.removeClass('active');
            $(targetClass).addClass('active');
        }                
     });            
});
```

Now, How can I make the color of each menu item be different at my preference?
Eg:
If I scroll down to about,it should change the menu item color to green.
[image]
For products and services, the menu item should be orange...and so forth for the others.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your scrolling function like this:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
            $('nav#site-navigation').addClass('fixed');
            $("a.marker.active:contains(About)").addClass('item-2');        
            $("a.marker.active:contains(Products)").addClass('item-3');
            $("a.marker.active:contains(Scent)").addClass('item-4');
            $("a.marker.active:contains(Clients)").addClass('item-5');
            $("a.marker.active:contains(Contact)").addClass('item-6');
        } else {
            $('nav#site-navigation').removeClass('fixed');        
        }
    });
```

In your stylesheet you can simply target each class that you added and play around with it.
Eg:

```
a.marker.item-2.active {
    color: rgba(213, 221, 45, 0.6) !important;
}
```

Let me know if it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Check out 'ScrollSpy'. It is a Bootstrap JS that does exactly what you want. I hope it answers your question. :)

Comment: Can you send a snippet of what you're referring that actually works?

Comment: Refer to this link: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_scrollspy_animate&stacked=h

Comment: I tested this code before using jquery and it is not much useful for the things am trying to achieve with wordpress. but thanks for the attempt

Comment: Hmm i thought it was possible if you alter the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

i think this jquery script will help you

```
$(".colors .main-navigation ul.nav >li").each(function(i) {
 $(this).addClass("colors"+(i+1));
});
```

This code help you to add you li element add a different class like color1, color2 color3 and then you style it on you own.

what to change:

```
$(".colors .main-navigation ul.nav >li")
```

change

```
your ul
```

Comment: there is an modification of replace .colors .main-navigation ul.nav >li to  your ul li

Answer (score 0):

Since you already toggle the the class `active` for the currently active item you could simply give each item an `id` (or a specific `class` like `.item-1`, `.item-2` etc.) as well and style them through CSS:

```css
#idOfItem1.active {
  color: yellow;
}

#idOfItem2.active {
  color: red;
}
// etc.
```

Comment: It is not really working. where exactly should I add that?
I am trying to use the contains method like this:$("a.marker.active:contains(Products)").css("color", "red");
It adds the color, but does not remove it when I go to a different section.

Comment: You don't need to use Javascript for this, but simple CSS.

Comment: I just did it as you explained...but the colors are only changing properly when I start scrolling for the second time. 
For the first time, when I scroll to the about section,the about menu item does not change color.It only changes when am almost at the end of the section. So for the products&services, only changes when am almost reaching scent marketing section.